# issue with js not working in responsive site

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the [following web page](http://www.shopious.com/items/8992987/Hi-Magician) , and when clicking on the orange button 'HUBUNGI PENJUAL' on a desktop site it works, it revealed the content behind it. However it seems that any click event on the responsive site (try to narrow down the window to 320px of width), it doesn't work. I am pulling out my hair trying to solve this.

Comment: Connection refused; can't debug.

Comment: Same issue as Daedalus.

Comment: @Daedalus try again , i just restarted server

Answer (score 1):

There's an h3 element blocking it with the text 'KOMENTAR' in it. It shows correctly but that h3 is rendering on top of the anchor tag. If you do $(".contact-beli").click() the other stuff shows which indicates the click event is never getting there.

If you add "clear: both;" to the column below the container of that button it seems to fix it. I'm not sure what's going on, seems like some sort of float/document flow issue.

Comment: add "clear: both;" to the column below the container of that button it seems to fix it , container of KOMENTAR or HUBUNGI PENJUAL

Comment: are you saying turn it to <div class="box-item2 clearfix" style="position:relative; clear: both;">